# What kind of external components would be required to use a MEAN WELL IRM-03-3.3 power supply?

Tags: power-supply

[Their datasheets](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/2239525.pdf) don't give any indication if any external components should be used to correctly and safely use these small power supplies. I've seen in other datasheets them using a varistor, various fuses (slow burn and thermal cutoffs), and capacitors but not here. Could I run this as is or am I overlooking something?

Comment: The bullet-points on the first page state *"Comply with EN55032 Class B without
any additional components."*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *What kind of external components would be required to use an MEAN WELL
> IRM-03-3.3 power supply?*

These devices are fully compliant with their specifications and do not need further components around them to meet the specifications that they state in their data sheet: -

[image]

You should be aware that clearance and creepage between input AC tracks and output DC tracks/components are needed of course. You may also need to add filters (or post regulation) to the output DC rails if you need an improved ripple voltage. See also note 2: -

[image]

This indicates to me that the ripple voltage may be several hundred mV at the terminals of the device (rather than the 100 mV p-p specified in the earlier section of the data sheet) so, you may choose to apply an LC low-pass filter to improve this situation.

Before using any device like this you should also check the [manufacturer's website](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-single-output-encapsulated-power-supply-pcb-irm--03--3.3) for supplementary information such as this usage requirement: -

[image]

This is telling me that the device is potentially restricted to household use only. What this could mean is that it's resilience to AC surges (such as indirect lightning surges) may not be "so good" in an industrial situation. You would need to contact Mean Well about this if not using the device on a domestic supply.

You should also read the [Installation Manual](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/IRM-03/PCB.pdf).

Comment: I'm going to use these power supplies too, but was wondering... do they have an internal fuse?

Comment: Almost certainly they will use internal fuses on the AC circuits in case there is a short-circuit that could overload AC wiring @bobflux

Comment: @bobflux Output overload has hiccup protection.

Comment: @tobalt of course, but the fuse is more about protecting against a dead shorted switching device starting a fire, that kind of stuff, so I was wondering if I should add it or not. It would be nice if the datasheet mentioned it.

Comment: It's incorrect that EN 60335 means the power supply is not suitable for industrial use. It is the opposite: EN 60335 has more stringent, i.e. larger, clearance and creepage requirements than 62368-1. It is a good thing.

Comment: @user71659 I didn't phrase it very well in my answer; the Mean Well power supply clearly passes EN 60335 (a domestic specification) but, domestic line surges (a different specification) may be less problematic to pass than line surges in industrial environments. Or, put differently, there may be something about the device that makes it unreliable in an industrial environment. Confirm with the manufacturer is always sensible.